# Raycasting in all direction from the source in three js

Tags: three.js

I am working with RayCasting in three js from couple of days and have understood how it works.
at the moment I am able to intersect the object using raycasting but I am up with one problem.

I am trying to find if there is any obstacle intersecting my 5 meter away from my source and I am looking to check this 5 meter in all the direction(similar like a boundary of 5 meters around the object).
right now with what I am doing it only checks at one.

so can someone help me how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Using raycasting is not a precise and performant approach for this kind of collision detection since you would have to cast an infinite number of rays to produce a 100% reliable result.

You should work with bounding volumes instead and perform intersection tests between those. `three.js` provides a [bounding sphere](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Sphere) and [AABB](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Box3) implementation in the core which are sufficiently tight bounding volumes for many use cases. You can also give the new
[OBB](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/math/OBB) class a try which is located in the examples. All three classes provide methods for intersection tests between all types.